# git subtree split "No new revisions were found"

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've been using `git subtree split` to divide up one huge repository, imported to Git from another VCS, into smaller repositories.

```
$ git subtree split -P ./path/to/folder/ -b folder-only
```

This has been working and I've moved a couple of folders out into new repositories but attempts on their siblings, after running through all the available commits, have **no branch created**.

The final message is

> "No new revisions were found"

I don't know if this is important or not but running with `--debug` gives messages like the following

> Processing commit: ca9d25944cf34bbe7aa356248a166ac1fb813f2a
>     parents: fc0e5a621ab871b8a11071eec321f4b40b8dcce0
>     newparents:
>     tree is:

Why has `git subtree split` failed and what can I do about it?

Comment: This works:  `git subtree split --prefix="path/to/folder" -b folder-only`

Comment: no it doesn't, it's the same as above

Answer (score 20):

I had the same symptoms when my `--prefix` was pointing to a directory that was not known to git. In my case I had a too aggressive `.gitignore` configuration.

So, to clarify my suggestions.

Make sure your:

1. `--prefix` folder is known to git. If needed `add` and `commit` it first.
2. `.gitignore` file doesn't rule out your desired directory.

I hope this helps, or at least gives you a hint in the right direction.

Comment: In some cases, might be better to keep it in .gitignore and then rsync to another folder that represents the other repo

Answer (score 9):

At least on my Windows 10 environment, the directory you specify with the -P (--prefix) parameter in `git subtree split` **is case sensitive**. I was having the same problem as the OP until I tried the same command making sure to get the directory casing correct.

So if you're trying to split the `Utility` folder from `c:\repo\Utility`, you have to do `git subtree split -P Utility ...`, not `git subtree split -P utility ...`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I tried to connect a subfolder in one repo as a subtree folder in other repo, the problem was related that I just confused path prefixes. Namely, I tried to use the targer repo path prefix where I should have used the source path prefix and vice versa.

When I set path prefixes correctly, everything started to work correctly.

More details. In a scenario like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386041/1183633) answer, part 3. git subtree. Merging the four files from contrib/completion/ of https://github.com/git/git.git into third_party/git_completion/ of the local repository. In code fragment:

```
# Do this the first time:
$ git remote add -f -t master --no-tags gitgit https://github.com/git/git.git
$ git checkout gitgit/master
$ git subtree split -P contrib/completion -b temporary-split-branch
$ git checkout master
$ git subtree add --squash -P third_party/git-completion temporary-split-branch
$ git branch -D temporary-split-branch
```

accidentally, I just wrote `contrib/completion` in place of `third_party/git-completion` which was incorrect and lead to this error. Placing prefixes to correct lines made it working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Git subtree is apparently case sensitive in this way as well, this is on Windows 10 using Git 2.34.1:

I changed a single character in the folder name from lower case to upper case a while ago. Git subtree split resulted in the same message: "No new revisions were found".

Temporarily changing back the case while subtree splitting solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a newbie I expected that after using `git subtree split`, I would be able to see the new branch online. However the **branch is created locally**. In order to see all local branches use

```
git branch
```

Also see related question

[Push changes from git subtree to a branch for a pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003831/push-changes-from-git-subtree-to-a-branch-for-a-pull-request)