# Push changes from git subtree to a branch for a pull request

Tags: git, git-subtree

How can I create local changes to a `git subtree` and then push those changes to a branch in the subtree's repo so that I can then create a pull request to merge the changes from that branch into the subtree's `master`?

Assume I have two repos, `project` and `protocols`, both of which are under my control.

**Step 1: add `protocols` as a `subtree` in the `project` repo**

```
$ git remote add protocols git@bitbucket.org:corp/protocols.git

$ git remote
origin
protocols

$ git subtree add --prefix=protocols protocols master --squash
...
From bitbucket.org:corp/protocols
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      master     -> protocols/master
Added dir 'protocols'
```

**Step 2: make some changes in the `project` repo to files that are in the `protocols` subtree**

```
$ cd protocols
$ echo "foo" > some_file
$ git commit -a -m "added foo"
```

**Step 3: create a branch in the `protocols` repo and push my local changes from `project/protocols` subtree to that branch**

??

I'm unsure as to how best to achieve this...

Once my `subtree` changes have been successfully pushed to a branch in the  remote `protocols` repo, I can then create a pull-request to merge those changes back into the `protocols` `master`.

**Questions:**

- I have a local copy of `protocols`. Should I change to that repository, create a branch, and then change back to `project` and push the `subtree` changes to my local `protocols` repo?
- Can I push the `subtree` changes *directly to a new branch* (as of yet uncreated) in my **local** `protocols` repo?
- Can I push the `subtree` changes *directly to a new branch* (as of yet uncreated) in the **remote** `protocols` repo?
- Is this a recommended workflow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **create a branch in the protocols repo and push my local changes from project/protocols subtree to that branch**

You can achieve that with a single command, `subtree push`, specifying a new remote branch:

```
$ git subtree push --prefix=protocols protocols feature
```

This will create a new branch, `feature` in the remote repository `protocols`

you can now create a pull request to merge the `feature` branch back into the `master` branch of protocols.

Once the branch has been merged back, you can update your subtree using a `pull` with `--squash`

```
$ git subtree pull --prefix=protocols protocols master --squash
```

This will create another commit with all the changes in the `protocols` repo squashed into one, and then a merge commit to merge into your `project` repo

Note there is a slight quirk to this method, and that is there will now be two commits in your `project` repo which contain the changes to the `protocols` repo.

- The original commit made in the `project` repo's `protocols` subtree
- The commit created by a subsequent subtree pull (typically along with other protocol changes, assuming `--squash` was used)

Comment: I used explicit `git subtree split` followed by `git push` to the subtree's original repository. This worked "fine", but resulted in an orphaned branch that I can't merge into master, so I can't "now create a pull request" as you suggest. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: @yoyo I have never used an explicit `subtree split` I'm afraid, so can't help, sorry!

Comment: Pushing this to the subtree repo brings all the history of the project branch to feature branch of protocols, is there a solution to avoid this?

Comment: @RichaDua I did not - did you find a way to avoid it?

Comment: @SteveLorimer I found a solution for this using subtree strategy merge. Everytime some one new in the team clones a repo with subtree links in it, they no longer have that mapping so the solution I found was using subtree strategy merge for pulling and pushing changes to the subtree repo.

For example the steps for pulling changes from subtree repo are:
 *1. git checkout -b <feature_branch>
 2. git remote add -f <remote_name> <subtree repo url>
 3. git merge --squash -s subtree --allow-unrelated-histories --no-commit <remote_name>/dev
        4. Add, commit and push the feature branch.*

Comment: Doing this my PR is not mergable. My SCM throws this error when trying to merge `Unrelated branches`