# How do I split a subdirectory into its own repository?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I've got a Python library of my own in a Git repository. I'm starting a new Python application in a new Git repository, which requires the use of a subdirectory of that library, which I will surely modify.

How do I import a subfolder of the library's repo to the application repo, in a way that the modifications made during the application development can be taken back to the library's repo at the end. During the application development, the library itself will also evolve on its own.

I've seen `git subtree` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266785/how-can-i-add-a-specific-folder-when-using-git-subtree) as an option to include a subfolder of a repo into another one, but I can't foresee how to take changes back to the library repo and merge them with the commits the library itself may have received meanwhile.

Comment: `git subtree push`, `git subtree pull`. Docs: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt, https://git-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subtree.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found the way to send back the results, these are the commands in case they help someone in the future.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269131/5239330):

Before adding the subtree to `my-app-repo`, split a subtree from `my-company-library-repo`:

```
# In my-company-library-repo
git subtree split -P src/app/providers/... -b feature-new feature
```

This will create a new history with the contents of `src/app/providers/...` at the root of the repo, starting at the `feature` branch, and create the branch `feature-new` at the end of this history.

Then add that new branch as a subtree to `my-app-repo`:

```
# In my-app-repo
git subtree add -P <destination-dir/feature> --squash <my-company-library-repo> feature-new
```

I complete with the commands to update `my-company-library-repo` with changes from `my-app-repo`

```
git subtree push -P <destination-dir/feature> <my-company-library-repo> feature-new
```

This will split the changes from `<destination-dir/feature>`, push them to the branch `feature-new` of `my-company-library-repo`. Then the commits can be merged/rebased into master of `my-company-library-repo`

Comment: Right on! The [subtree "split"](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt#L101) command is exactly right.