# How to keep different folders in different repositories in sync? (Only certain folders not the whole repo)

Tags: git, synchronization, repository, git-submodules

I am currently examining git submodules, one part of my question can be solved with it. As I've understood submodules do synch **a whole remote** repo with a  directory in my current repo (maybe I'm wrong).

What I would like to achieve would be to keep **only certain folders in different repositories** in synch, an Example:

```
REPO X -> folder A -> subfolder "contract" should be in sync with
REPO Y -> folder B -> subfolder "s1" -> subfolder "contract"
```

Is that possible with submodules? If not, is there another way?

Comment: When you say 2 folders each from different repos should be in sync, you mean they should be in sync with a common remote repo ?

Comment: there is currently no common repo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add subdirectory of remote repo with git-subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937436/add-subdirectory-of-remote-repo-with-git-subtree) , In your case, you can assume Repo Y as remote repo and remote repo's URL will just be the absolute path of RepoY

Comment: Yes, it has helped, thank you!