# Is there a simpler way to publish from a monorepo to their different repos?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-subtree, git-tag

I have a monorepo with yarn workspaces (and lerna)

```
-package
--one
--two
-site
```

And a script that takes each one of them (**one**, **two** and **site**) and pushes them to their github repositories

I do this with something like

```sh
git subtree split ... // from `one|two|site` folders create a new repo
git checkout ... // switch to the new repo
git tag ... // create a tag and push it to the new repo
git push -u url branch:master // push the content to the new repo
git checkout master // go back
git branch --delete // delete the created brancg
```

It (so far) works, even though it is slow

The question is whether I am doing this correctly or there is any other better solution out there

Comment: Did you consider submodules?

Comment: Let me confirm my understanding of your structure. The monorepo is in fact read/write git repo, where all the work is done. While "one", "two", "three" are readonly git repos presumably for distribution. Is this right?

Comment: @sbat yes, that's right

Comment: @VonC do they work better than subtree? I remember I looked into that but I decided to go with subtree (don't remember why though)

Comment: I find them easier to manipulate. And tagging them all in one go is possible, as I proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58254305/6309

Comment: It looks like Lerna leave this to the end user, but unofficially blesses https://github.com/splitsh/lite . See the discussion here https://github.com/lerna/lerna#git-hosted-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The initial subtree split seems OK, but you might want to double-check example 3.

> Suppose you have a source directory with many files and
>   subdirectories, and you want to extract the lib directory to its own
>   git project. Here's a short way to do it:
>
> First, make the new repository wherever you want:
>
> ```
> $ <go to the new location>    
> $ git init --bare
> ```
>
> Back in your original directory:
>
> ```
> $ git subtree split --prefix=lib --annotate="(split)" -b split
> ```
>
> Then push the new branch onto the new empty repository:
>
> ```
> $ git push <new-repo> split:master
> ```

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt

Anyway, following that, if this monorepo is the "write" repository, you should be able to simply subtree push updates to the remotes.

```
git subtree push --prefix package/one remote-one master
```

There is some fuss about pushes taking longer and longer (the more commits the repository collects), so there's some info here about using the rejoin option with your split.

[How can I reduce the ever-increasing time to push a subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16134975/3619)